# How can I find the ID of a document that has a field of a specific value

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection 'users', which has documents. Each user document has a collection called 'devices'. In the 'devices' collection there is one device document. A device document has a field called 'serial number'.

users -> user documents -> devices -> device document -> serial number field

I receive the serial number, and want to find out the document id of the user to which the serial number belongs to.
How can I do this?

What I have done till now is:

```
const usersReference = firestoreDb.collection("users");
```

I then tried using a for in to loop through every document but I am getting errors.
What is the correct solution to this?

Comment: What language or technology are you using ? Plain JS, Angular ...?

Comment: I am using node js

Answer (score 0):

**The proper way is to get a document path:**

From DocumentReference: .path

```
var path = ref.path
```

From DocumentSnapshot: .ref.path

```
var path = doc.ref.path
```

Then you split the path with '/' and you get the second element from the array